# Pointer "not accessible" in CPP

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

Good morning everyone.

I want to call my own function, contained by a parent, which interpolate a value into a table.

When I call the the function by it self, the interpolation works. But, when I call the same function, passing by the get method of the parent, the program terminates with the error code -1.

Here is my function header:

```
class TabulatedFunction  : public AbstractUnivariateFunction , public AbstractClass {
public:
   TabulatedFunction();
   TabulatedFunction(float ** table, InterpolatorMode mode);
   virtual ~TabulatedFunction();
   float calculate(float* x);
   void setTabulatedValues(float ** table);
   float** getTabulatedValues();
   InterpolatorMode getMode();
   void setMode(InterpolatorMode mode);

private:
   float** tabulatedValues;
   InterpolatorMode mode;
};
```

Here the implementation

```
float TabulatedFunction::calculate(float* xx){
float y=0.;
float x = xx[0];

// Interpolate threw the table
switch (mode) {
case InterpolatorMode::LINEAR:
{
    double diffByLow = 10000000.;
    double diffByUp = -1000000.;
    int iByLow = -1;
    int iByUp = -1;

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tabulatedValues[0][0]) ; i++ ){
        float diff = tabulatedValues[i][0] - x;
        if(fabs(diff) < diffByLow && diff < 0){
            diffByLow = fabs(diff);
            iByLow = i;
        }
        if(fabs(diff) < diffByUp && diff > 0){
            iByUp = i;
            diffByUp = fabs(diff);
        }
    }

    if(iByUp == -1){
        iByLow = sizeof(tabulatedValues[0][0])-2;
        iByUp = sizeof(tabulatedValues[0][0])-1;
    }
    else if(iByLow == -1){
        iByLow = 0;
        iByUp = 1;
    }
    cout << iByLow << endl;
    y = tabulatedValues[iByLow][1] +(x - tabulatedValues[iByLow][0]) *(tabulatedValues[iByUp][1] - tabulatedValues[iByLow][1])/((tabulatedValues[iByUp][0] - tabulatedValues[iByLow][0]));

}break;
case InterpolatorMode::TRIGONOMETRIC:
{
    y=0.;
}break;

default:{
    y=0.;
}break;
}

return y;
}
```

And then, the declaration of the function into my parent:

```
class TabulatedDynamicsModel : public AbstractDynamicsModel {
public:
   TabulatedDynamicsModel();
   virtual ~TabulatedDynamicsModel();



   void setThrustVsSpeedFunction(TabulatedFunction* thrustVsSpeedFunction);
   TabulatedFunction* getThrustVsSpeedFunction();

   TabulatedFunction* getAttitudeFunction();
   void setAttitudeFunction(TabulatedFunction* attitude);

private:
   TabulatedFunction thrustVsSpeedFunction;
   TabulatedFunction attitude;

};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Way too much code, but I don't see any `get` method. Reduce your issue to a minimal example that reproduces the problem and post that.

Comment: (also read [mcve])

Comment: You say the code works when you call it one way, but crashes when you call it in another way.   But you haven't shown any code that calls your function AT ALL.   Only obvious problem in your code, as shown, is that `sizeof` is being seriously misused.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is this line

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tabulatedValues[0][0]) ; i++ ){
```

`tabulatedValues` is define as `float**` and `sizeof` applied on `tabulatedValues[0][0]` doesn't give you the number of elements of the second dimension of the array.

On my computer (gcc 64 bits) this returns:

`sizeof(tabulatedValues)` = `sizeof(float **)` = `8`

`sizeof(tabulatedValues[0])` = `sizeof(float *)` = `8`

`sizeof(tabulatedValues[0][0])` = `sizeof(float)` = `4`

If you define `tabulatedValues` as `float tabulatedValues[rows][cols]` then you can calculate the number of elements of the second dimension (`cols`) using:

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tabulatedValues[0] / tabulatedValues[0][0]) ; i++ ){
```

or simply

```
for(int i=0;i<boost::size(tabulatedValues[0]) ; i++ ){ // or std::size() on C++17
```

But as fas as you use pointers, you should provide the size (number of cols per row) as a parameter to the function.